# How to stop select box selection text from wrapping in chrome browser?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I don't want the text of the selected option in my select box to wrap. It doesn't wrap in IE or firefox. It looks like

[image]

But in the Chrome browser it looks like

[image]

How can I make the text not wrap in the Chrome browser?

Comment: I had this same problem but I had set already set a height on the `select`. So, the box stayed the same height but there was just an empty margin-like space below the select box where the wrapped text would have been! The answer solved this also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried using the `white-space: nowrap;` CSS property? It should push your text into one line.  You might also need to use `width:auto` on your `<select>` box - I'm not sure if I can give any more guidance without seeing your markup and CSS.